# Rails Active Storage without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Can Rails Active Storage be used without a model backing it?   I have a form where I need a file to be uploaded but I don't wish it to be attached to a model. I just need the file uploaded so I can process it with a background job and then delete it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes.

When ActiveStorage is backed by a model, there are two parts involved:

- An `ActiveStorage::Blob` record that holds the file info in the `active_storage_blobs` table
- An `ActiveStorage::Attachment` record that connects the blob to the model using the `active_storage_attachments` table

You can skip creating the `ActiveStorage::Attachment` record if you call [`create_and_upload!`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L112) directly.  This will create a unique key, determine the content type, compute a checksum, store an entry in `active_storage_blobs`, and upload the file:

```rb
filename = 'local_file.txt'
file = File.open(filename)
blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_and_upload!(io: file, filename: filename)
```

You can download later with:

```rb
blob.download
```

And delete with:

```rb
blob.purge
```

---

If you want to skip the storage of the `ActiveStorage::Blob` entirely, you would need to go directly to the storage service that manages uploading and downloading files.  For example, if you are using `Disk` storage you'd see something like this:

```rb
ActiveStorage::Blob.service
 => #<ActiveStorage::Service::DiskService ...
```

Then you'd have to generate your own key and do something like:

```rb
service = ActiveStorage::Blob.service
key = 'some_unique_key'
service.upload(key, file)
service.download(key)
service.delete(key)
```

---

To upload a file without a model you can [use `form_with` and specify a `url`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files) like:

```rb
<%= form_with url: "/uploads", multipart: true do |form| %>
  <%= form.file_field :picture %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then on the server you can get the `file` with:

```rb
file = params[:picture]
blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_and_upload!(io: file, filename: file.original_filename)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  How would I combine that with a file upload from a form?  I can't open a file to make a blob when the file hasn't been uploaded if you know what I mean?

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: Fantastic. That's perfect.  I should be able to continue building from this!  Thanks so much!

Comment: This is a top quality answer, thanks. @rctneil you should accept this

Comment: @Barry Very true, Accepted!

Comment: @cschroed I am using the exact same thing. I am able to see Insert into Active::Storage::Blobs table in the logs but the database table is not showing the record. What could be the reason? Also Active::Storage::Blob.last doesn't give back the record it created using create_and_upload!